# How to trigger hover when mouse on a child div

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
<div id='hasHover'>
  <div id='inner-button' style='display:none'>Click</div>
</div>

$('#hasHover').hover(function(){
  $('inner-button').toggle();
});
```

This works fine. However when I move my mouse to the button, the button disappears(or flashes really fast). How to make sure the button stays when the mouse is hovering on the div (including child div)?

Comment: `#hasHover:hover div { display: block }`

Comment: @undefined I tried and it works when I put `display: block !important`. If I don't put important, it does not work. Why is that?

Comment: @undefined Oh I see. I put `display:none` after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#hasHover').hover(function(e) { // <-- Create event argument
  if(e.target.id == "hasHover") { // <-- Check the ID of the div on which event fired
     $('#inner-button').toggle(); // <-- You missed # here
     return false;
  }
  else {
     return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: You mean `id == 'hasHover'`?

Comment: Also it still flashes, although not as frequent. I am not sure if there is a better solution to toggle the button?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MvAfX/1/ It is weird that in fiddle it works fine...In my website it flashes. Maybe there is some other styles affecting it...

Answer (score 0):

check the target id

```
$('#hasHover').hover(function(e) {
   if(e.target.id = "hasHover") {
      $('inner-button').toggle();
   return false;
   }else {
    return false;
   }
});
```